# Too many Ender Dragons made The End very laggy

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son's friend put a pressure plate to spawn unlimited Ender Dragons. I have destroyed the plate and used the kill command `/kill@e[type=ender_dragon]` but the world is very laggy.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to break the command blocks?

Comment: Yes I did break the command blocks then I enter the kill command but the world is still laggy

Answer (score 4):

I assume that may be because there are other dragons out of render distance. Perhaps fly around and do the command a few more times just to check. Other than that I see no reason why it would still be laggy. Also, dragons do not drop xp unless killed by the player (they do not drop xp when killed by a command).

Edit: unless youve built things in the end, you could just reset it. In other words, you can hard reset the end dimension by going into the world folder and deleting any end dimension files.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you mean by "reset it"?

Answer (score 0):

*Killing the ender dragon spawns a lot of XP. Try running `/kill @e[type=xp_orb]` to get rid of the XP orbs.*

**Edit (credit @Aceplante): Mobs do not drop XP unless killed by a player.**